# subsonic query problem

Tags: subsonic

I'm using subsonic 2.2 in an app. I'm running a little complicated query in I have used both "And" and "Or" for a field, I'm little confused about how it is going to be translated into sql statement

```
MytableCollection col = DB.Select().From("mytable").Where("prop1").IsEqualTo(obj.prop1)
                .And("prop2").IsEqualTo(obj.prop2)
                .And("prop3").IsEqualTo(obj.prop3)
                .Or("prop1").IsEqualTo(1)                
                .ExecuteAsCollection<MytableCollection>();
```

I want to perform query like this.

```
select * from mytable where (prop1=obj.prop1 or prop1=1)  and prop2=obj.prop2 and prop23=obj.prop3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use expression in subsonic 2.2.

```
MytableCollection col  = new Select(Mytable.Schema)
.WhereExpression("prop1").IsEqualTo(obj.prop1).Or("prop1").IsEqualTo(1)
.AndExpression("prop2").IsEqualTo(obj.prop2)
.AndExpression("prop3").IsEqualTo(obj.prop3)
.ExecuteAsCollection<MytableCollection>();
```

Comment: Since the query only has one set of brackets you should only need one AndExpression

Comment: It would be like. select * from mytable where (prop1=obj.prop1 or prop1=1)  and ( prop2=obj.prop2 ) and ( prop23=obj.prop3 )

Answer (score 3):

As Andra says you can use AndExpression. This should do what you want:

```
MytableCollection col = DB.Select().From(Mytable.Schema)
  .Where(Mytable.Columns.Prop2).IsEqualTo(obj.prop2)
  .And(Mytable.Columns.Prop3).IsEqualTo(obj.prop3)
  .AndExpression(Mytable.Columns.Prop1).IsEqualTo(obj.prop1)
  .Or(Mytable.Columns.Prop1).IsEqualTo(1)                
  .ExecuteAsCollection<MytableCollection>();
```

N.B. using MyTable.Schema and MyTable.Columns will catch a lot of issues at compile time if you rename tablees and will save errors caused by mistyping

Answer (score 2):

Something that is REALLY useful to know about is also the following two methods to call in your query building:

```
.OpenExpression()
```

and

```
.CloseExpression()
```

Mix those bad buoys and you have a lot better control over knowing where things start and finish